# Memory warning and app crash when downloading images

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, crash, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` library, images are around 0.5 MB and displayed in `detailView` when clicked on `UITableViewCell`.

Code from detail view:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.imageURL)
    {
        [self.imageView setImageWithURL:self.imageURL placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize)
         {
             float percentDone = (float)receivedSize*200/(receivedSize+expectedSize);
             [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading... %0.0f%%", percentDone]];
             if (percentDone == 100) {
                 [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Loaded."];
             }
         }
                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {

         }];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}
```

Are the images too big (half megabyte)?
`SDWebImage` caches these images.

Comment: try to comment  [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading... %0.0f%%", percentDone]];

Comment: I will give it right away, just a sec to reproduce the crash

Comment: There is no crash log, just a few times of: Received memory warning.
And then the app shuts down

Comment: @MikhailViceman, I tried to comment that line, memory warning and crash still occurs.

Btw crashes don't occur on first image display, but after few of them.

Comment: make sure you are releasing images after closing the detailview

Comment: I am using ARC, how can I release them?

Comment: I have self.imageView = nil; in viewDidUnload

Answer (score 0):

you said you release the imageView.image in viewDidUnload but viewDidUnload is deprecated on ios6. views are no longer unloaded.. the method is likely not called :)

do it in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

Comment: I will try setting IBOutlet of UIImageView to weak

Comment: I have set IBoutlet property to (nonatomic, weak) and set it to nil in didReceiveMemoryWarning and I still get memory warnings and app crashes

Comment: Use Profile in XCode, to detect what cause memory warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In TABLEViewCell use SDWebImageProgressiveDownload is not a good idea ,use SDWebImageRetryFailed it will be fine